# Formatting month name abbreviation (Jan/Feb/...) within datetime

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to encode datetime format for strings that are of the form: '06JAN2018' or '31DEC2017'.

I think this is format = '%d[xxxx]%Y' but I don't know how to encode the month portion of it.

Is there a list anywhere of every type of encoding possible for this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The list of these codes is in the `datetime` module's [strftime() and strptime() Behavior](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) documentation.

> `%b`: Month as locale’s abbreviated name.

In your case, `06JAN2018` is `%d%b%Y`.

---

If what you're actually looking to do is to encode a datetime object or Pandas/NumPy datetime array to strings, you'll probably need to do the uppercasing yourself:

```
>>> dt = datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 31)
>>> dt.strftime('%d%b%Y').upper()  # or .str.upper() in Pandas
'31DEC2017'
```